# Spring boot embedded Kafka integration throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Spring Boot: 2.0.3.RELEASE

org.apache.kafka.kafka-streams: 1.0.0

org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients: 1.0.0

org.springframwork.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.1.7.RELEASE

I have a working Spring boot application with Kafka. I am trying to follow https://blog.mimacom.com/testing-apache-kafka-with-spring-boot/ to create an integration test.

When I add the @EmbeddedKafka annotation I get the error when I run

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaEmbedded': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/record/RecordFormat
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

There are a few google results on this error however they are all on old kafka-client versions and they should be fixed in the version I use.

This looks like a version mismatch but it is not clear to me what I am supposed to me.

Comment: if possible can you share your codebase?

Comment: it's a problem caused by kafka version compatibility

Comment: It would take me a while to get a working sample that can be publicly distributed. I have shown a pom here https://gist.github.com/renedescartes/5c1a54cd2f5a083ee39450863f4e7359 if that does not give away anything I'll try to create a working app

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi Very likely could you look at the pom https://gist.github.com/renedescartes/5c1a54cd2f5a083ee39450863f4e7359 and tell me which two are conflicting?

Comment: try to upgrade kafka-clients to 2.2.0

Comment: why not add `spring-kafka` library ?

Comment: works for me, using latest spring boot-2.1.4, kafka-client-2.0.1,

Comment: Please check the compatibility matrix: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka, this will be the main reason if there is a mismatch in client and broker(embedded-kafka) version

Comment: Here is working sample: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/c01148ef544c4c97aa8a08668c3b326d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments errors like these are always due to library version incompatibilities. The following combination worked

```
spring boot: 2.1
spring-streams/spring-client: 2.0.1 (Using 2.2.0 creates some compatibility issues)
spring-kafka: 2.2.5.RELEASE
```